# How to intercept multiple http request in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8

I am implementing a Splunk logging concept using Angular Interceptor.

I need to pass component information like ComponentName, ServiceName to the interceptor. I am able to pass through the Subject but when there are multiple calls at the same time and first call response is coming after 45 seconds and the second call response is coming after 5 seconds then I am not able to log the correct data, Second call data is getting mapped to the First Call Response.

Is there any way that we can identify which request is associated to which response?

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Interceptor, service, component

Comment: I can not show the code it is in the client machine.

Comment: are you asking about `forkJoin` rxjs operator? you want use a switchmap? In Angular generally you use rxjs to make severals calls (and only subscribe one time)

Comment: Hi Eliseo, both calls are handled separately I do not want to use switchMap and forkJoin. In the interceptor, we have finalize the method of rxjs that will execute for each observable of response But I need some identification for coming response is for which request since there can we multiple requests in the process.